# How do I populate fields with a blank value instead of "undefined" using URL Parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, undefined

My URL prepopulates a form using URL parameters that I have created. Currently, if the parameter isn't set the value will be populated by "undefined". I want this to be blank instead.

Here is the link to the website with the form that pre-populates:-

> www.test.co.uk/test/?ID=0000000000&App=L3%20Business%20Administrator&DOB=19/8/2019&FName=Test&SName=Test&Emp=Skillswork

This is the script that sets the parameters. What tweaks do I make to the script to populate with a blank value instead of "undefined"?

```
<script text="text/javascript"> 
     var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
         var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
             sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
             sParameterName,
             i;
         for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
             sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
             if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                 return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];


             }
         }
     };

     var VARIABLE = getUrlParameter('PARAMETER');

     if (VARIABLE != null) {
          document.getElementById('INPUT-FIELD-ID').value = VARIABLE;
     }

var NationalInsuranceNumber = getUrlParameter('Nin');
var Gender = getUrlParameter('Gen');
var Address = getUrlParameter('Add');
var Postcode = getUrlParameter('Pcode');
var Email = getUrlParameter('Email');
var Mobile = getUrlParameter('Mob');
var HomeNumber = getUrlParameter('Home');

document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWV').value = NationalInsuranceNumber;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWk').value = Gender;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWa').value = Address;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWf').value = Postcode;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWp').value = Email;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWu').value = Mobile;
document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuWz').value = HomeNumber;
</script>
```

I'm hoping to populate the fields with "blank" values instead of "undefined"

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parameter `Nin` is null or undefined, this code assigns "" to NationalInsuranceNumber.

```
var NationalInsuranceNumber = getUrlParameter('Nin') || "";
```

It's shorthand from

```
if (getUrlParameter("Nin")) {
  NationalInsuranceNumber = getUrlParameter('Nin');
}else{
  NationalInsuranceNumber = getUrlParameter('Nin');
}
```

Comment: That does exactly what I require thank you for helping resolve the issue.

Comment: Only if you're sure the values can never be falsey... E.G. when you have `something = 0;` then `something || ""` will output the empty string rather than "0".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator

`var NationalInsuranceNumber = getUrlParameter('Nin') ? getUrlParameter('Nin') : ""`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for undefined value everytime( Ex Nin, Pcode etc), this should be handled by getUrlParameter directly where we can check if the param is undefined and then return empty string starightaway.

Comment: You should show some example code to demonstrate what you mean. The casual visitor would remark that the routine already checks if the parameter is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is more better to return from getUrlParameter function when no match found like this

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
     var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
         sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
         sParameterName,
         i;
     for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
         sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
         if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
             return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];


         }
     }
return '';
 };
```

or let your code look more simple

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
     var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
         found = sPageURL.split('&').find((p)=>p.includes(sParam))
        return found?found.split('=')[1]:'';
 };
```

Comment: The issue I get with this method are that checkboxes don't populate, I could be setting them wrong though. This is what I do currently document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuXd').checked = AllowContactViaPhoneCK;

Comment: document.getElementById('00N1n00000SwuXd').checked = getUrlParameter('useYourParamNameHere') 
it should work and make sure you are passing the right param value as true or false or anything equivalent